# I want use jQuery to select a list item that will use Razor to bring up a PartialView

Tags: jquery, list, razor, model-view-controller, partial-views

I have set the value of the Tabs List, proven with the alert.  However, the Create Partial view is reloaded I want to force it to go to the PartialView I select. So in my example I want  the user to:

1. select from a list of BirthdayIDs,
2. then the main view refreshes,
3. then the screen should not go to the first on the list, but I want to get from a saved value (for now I want to just plug it into the list option value.

   ```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Birthday", FormMethod.Post, new { id     = "frmBirthday", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
   {
           <input type="hidden" id="hdnAction" name="Action" />
           @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedBirthdayID, new { @class = "table-label" }) 
           @:&nbsp;
           @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedBirthdayID,  Model.BirthdayIDs, "Select...", new { id = "ddlBirthdayID", width = "250px" })  @:&nbsp;
           @:&nbsp; 
           @Html.ActionLink("Create New Birthday Party", "Index", "Birthday")   <br /><br /> 


           <div id="tabs">
               <ul>
                   <li><a href="#Create">Birthday Create</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#Cards">Cards</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#Gifts">Gifts</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#Guests">Guests</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#Food">Food</a></li>
               </ul>

               <div id="Create">
                    @Html.Partial("_Create")
               </div>

           <div id="Cards" >
               @Html.Partial("_Cards")
           </div>

           <div id="Gifts">
               @Html.Partial("_Gifts")
           </div>

           <div id="Guests">
               @Html.Partial("_Guests")
           </div>

           <div id="Food">
               @Html.Partial("_Food")
           </div>

       </div>
   ```

   }

   //jQuery

   $(function () {
           $("#tabs").tabs();

   ```
       $('#ddlBirthdayID').change(function () {
           $('#hdnAction').val("ddlchange");
           $('#frmBirthday').submit();
       });

       $('#ddlBirthdayID').change(function () {
           $('#tabs').val(3);
           alert($("#tabs").val());
       });
   ```

Comment: The above code is in the Index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to mix client and server-side technologies. Partials are rendered when the page is delivered. Selections happen client-side only.

**Your options are:**

- Refresh the full page with different partials (e.g. based on an extra parameter to choose the selection)
- render all partials and simply hide the partial you do not want, and show the selected one or
- load the partial views using Ajax (e.g. into a fixed panel), whenever the selection changes

e.g. To hide them use a common class on all those panels (initially hide them and let the client-side code show the required panel on selection change).

The correct choice depends on other factors about your pages, so more information is needed before I can say which option is best for your scenario.

*Note: To provide a better example you need to also show your controller actions and examples of the other views*